# Uploading an array of image with other parameters to php from xcode

Tags: php, arrays, xcode, swift3, alamofire

i am a beginner and i am not sure on how to go about submitting my array of image to my database using alamofire. Below is my code when it the form loads

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // adding page image into the image square
            for i in 1...3
            {
                var imgView : UIImageView!
                imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
                imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                imgView.tag = i
                imgView.image = UIImage(named: "page.png")
                imageArray.add(imgView)
            }

            videoView.isHidden = true
            photoView.type = iCarouselType.coverFlow2
            photoView.reloadData()
        }
```

After the user selects/take photo the image will replace page.png .. all that works fine. Below is the replacement code

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        self.selectedImageView.image = chosenImage

        imageArray.replaceObject(at: self.selectedImageView.tag-1, with: self.selectedImageView)

        photoView.reloadData()

        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And as for the submit part, i am having trouble with understand array and what more submitting an array to php/ database. please do help me put as i do not know how to continue from here. I need to submit the array of images (max 3 image) as well as other parameters in the form.

```
@IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any)
    {

            let URL_Submit = "http://localhost/form.php"
            let parameters: Parameters=[

                "block":blockText.text!,
                "category":catText.text!,
                "description":descText.text!]


            Alamofire.request(URL_Submit, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
                {

                    response in
                    //printing response
                    print(response)

                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message:
                        "Your feedback has been submitted", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

           }
```

I deleted my attempt to upload the image in my submitAction bc its not working. Please do help me put as i really have no clue on now to continue. Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you please tell me, is my answer resolved your issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multipart upload for uploading files to your server, like here is an example of uploading 4 images using `alamofire`. You can make an array and upload multiple images as well:

```
func uploadImagesAndData(params:[String : AnyObject]?,image1: UIImage,image2: UIImage,image3: UIImage,image4: UIImage,success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {

let imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5)!
let imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.5)!

let imageData3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image3, 0.5)!

let imageData4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image4, 0.5)!


Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    for (key, value) in params! {
        if let data = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
        }
    }

    //### Here "file" is the name of your image parameter ###//

    multipartFormData.append(imageData1, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    multipartFormData.append(imageData2, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    multipartFormData.append(imageData3, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    multipartFormData.append(imageData4, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

},
                 to: K_BASEURL + K_API_LOGINDATA, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload
                            .validate()
                            .responseJSON { response in
                                switch response.result {
                                case .success(let value):
                                    print("responseObject: \(value)")


                                    let resp = JSON(response.result)
                                    success(resp)
                                case .failure(let responseError):
                                    print("responseError: \(responseError)")
                                    failure(responseError)
                                }
                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print("encodingError: \(encodingError)")
                    }
 })
}
```

In your case, you can loop through your `array`. My backend has `thumb[]` check so I named it as `"thumb[]"`. you can have a different name:

```
  for thumbImg in thumbImagesArray {
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImg as! UIImage, 1)!, withName: "thumbs[]", fileName: "thumbs.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
```

Comment: I didn't get you, can you please update your question with the code and all the errors you are getting after using mine code?